# msbuild build and publish ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In our solution we have few projects: class libraries, console apps and webbaps on ASP.NET MVC. I'd like to publish console and web apps to directory. For console apps msbuild works like a charm. The worst part is with ASP.NET MVC applications. There are only dll's on the output directory. I tried build and deploy with PublishProfile property, but it doesn't help. Interestingly, everything is ok when I publish this profile on VS.

I think, I tried everything, but it didn't work. For example:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" C:\test\TestSol.sln /t:Apps\Webapp /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\Directory.pubxml" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

My profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>..\..\deploy</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I read something about msdeploy, but it didn't seems like solution for me.

How can I publish ASP.NET MVC application from console, like in VS?

Comment: I think you used the wrong msbuild version. What you used is from net framework sdk which does not contain most of the vs environment variables. You should use C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.And it is the official msbuild.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`. And this is the official version which contains all vs environment variables.

**However**, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe` is from framework sdk and can only do some simple build operations, cannot handle large and complex builds.

So you should use:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but it didn't work for me. Now i have "error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected". But when I compile and publish project in VS everything is still ok.

Comment: See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1003). You have some syntax errors on your code and you should check the error part which the log provided. Your VS cannot list the error due to some reasons and maybe you have installed some packages or extensions which prevents the errors. MSBuild command line is the right, most authoritative build tool. You should trust it.

Comment: You could also set `-v:detailed` to get the detailed build log. Please note that error xxx.cs(2,4).Such as this, the brackets refer to the wrong line number. You could check them or share the code with us to help you find the error out:)